# Angular 2 Django-Rest-Framework Authentication with http.post

Tags: curl, angular, http-headers, django-rest-framework

I have spent more time than I'd like to admit to find an answer to this question, but can't seem to figure it out on my own.
I have a Django-rest-api following [this tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/) and can use httpie or curl to communicate with the api and pass credentials. I also have an angular 2 SPA which can send http.get requests and get data back from the server. Everything works perfectly up until I try to use POST and pass authentication data from within the angular 2 app which results in a Http 403 (Forbidden).

Since the api works fine with curl, it makes me think I'm doing something wrong sending the http.post in angular. Here is my code:

```
postStuff() {
    var body = "username=myusername&password=mypassword";
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/rest/', body, { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

and here is a curl example that works fine:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -u myusername:mypassword http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/
```

Is there an 'Authorization' header that I need to include in the header?I tried Authorization:Basic but no luck. I also ran a curl to find the Allowed Options and POST is allowed.
I basically want the equivalent of the "-u username:password" from the curl in my http.post (or http.get if it is possible)

It may also be worth mentioning that on the parts of the api where no authentication is required, I get a 400 (Bad Request) using POST while GET works fine.
For example, this works fine:

```
return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/')
        .map(res => res.json())
```

and this does not:

```
return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/', { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res.json());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues needed to be addressed:

1 - On the angular side set the [withCredentials](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html#!#withCredentials-anchor) attribute to true:

```
return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/', 
{ headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
    .map(res => res.json());
```

2- On the Django side handle CSRF and Access Origin:
These and CORS are their own can of worms addressed in many other questions in stack overflow.